# Linq to Entities: adding a where condition to a child relationship

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

For example I have a list of customers which each have a list of orders. Now, I want to get a list of all customers with unpaid orders (let's say this is status 2). Together with that list of customers, I want to have the list of unpaid orders also.

For example I have this:

```
from c in mycontext.Customers.Include("Orders")
select c
```

Where or how do I add the condition to look for Orders with status == 2 and how to include these orders with the list of customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

otherwise

```
from c in mycontext.Customers.Include("Orders")
where c.Orders.Any(order => order.status == 2)
select c
```

or

```
from c in mycontext.Customers.Include("Orders")
let newObject = {
    Customer = c,
    NotPaidOrders = c.Orders.Where(order => order.status == 2).ToList()
}
where newObject.NotPaidOrders.Any()
select newObject
```

Comment: The usage of .Any has put me on the right track for a solution, thanks!

Comment: Note that should you also need the child entities that satisfied the condition, `Any()` can't be used cause if  `Any` of the `Orders` have `order.status == 2`, then ALL `Orders` will be selected.

Sorry if I resumed an old post, but I'm struggling with a similar issue and thought this could be the solution but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from c in mycontext.Customers.Include("Orders")
from order in c.Orders
where order.status == 2
select order
```

Or why not simply do this:

```
from order in mycontext.Orders
where order.status == 2
select order
```